# Adjective for 'big business'

Tags: adjectives, british-english

I'm looking for an adjective that means 'pertaining/relating to big businesses'. Currently I'm thinking of using **'big-business/large-business'** as an adjective, but I'm not sure if that's accepted.

Example of how it would be used:

- **Big-business software providers**: providers whose software is tailored towards large corporations/multinationals

Merriam-webster and Cambridge dictionary don't agree it's a word but I *think* the meaning is abundantly clear for the average reader. Are there any other/more elegant words that convey the same meaning?

(Of course, I could simply write 'for large businesses' and call it a day, but for reasons of spacing I need it to be as short/snappy as possible and I quite like noun stacking)

Comment: If the "software is tailored towards large corporations", why not use "corporate"?

Comment: ... Okay, I may have had a brain fart there. Both 'enterprise' and 'corporate' are good (and probably obvious) choices, thanks!

Comment: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/big-business) certainly lists 'big business' as a compound, and gives an attributive usage among its many examples. And [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/big%20business) certainly lists the compound 'big business', again with many examples. Admittedly, the prenominal reading is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use **enterprise software providers**.

[Cambridge Dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enterprise) defines *enterprise* as

> an organization, a company, or a business.

This is a bit broader than *big business*, but if you want to be more specific, you might have to say *"provider of software for large businesses"*.